# background: url returning ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html, css

I'm using a background image for my site with the following CSS code

```
body {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  hyphens: auto;
    margin: auto; 
  background: url(/images/store_interior.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover cover;
  height: 100vh; }
```

However, when I view the site (local view, I haven't ftp'd my entire site yet), my browser (Edge) is telling me the following: **GET file:///C:/images/store_interior.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND style.css:1**
The image file is siting in images. I'm not sure why this isn't working at all and any other image I've tried from that file is not working as a background image either.

Comment: you using a relative path to the CSS file. Bes would be to use a folder for your entire website that is uploaded via FTP to maintain its file structure.

Comment: My entire site has a folder currently. Inside it are two folders: images and css. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: yes add your file structure so we can give you a more precise answer. Sounds to me, that your url should be: `"../images/store_interior.jpg"`

Comment: Ohh, thank you so much! It works now.

Answer (score 2):

Your provided CSS indicates following file structure:

```
Root Folder
├─ index.html
├─ style.css
└─ images
   └─ store_interior.jpg
```

However your comment indicates this file structure:

```
Root Folder
├─ index.html
├─ css
│  └─ style.css
└─ images
   └─ store_interior.jpg
```

Relative pathes within a CSS file are relative to the CSS file itself not relative to the root folder.
As such you need to use `../` to go one folder down. Means to leave the css folder back to the root folder. Then you can use `images/` to actually enter the images folder.
The correct path should be: `../images/store_interior.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this
"../images/store_interior.jpg"